# Displaying two decimal price rounded with one decimal in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, rounding, price

Been working on a message that informs the customer about the shipping and if he/she spends another XX dollars, free shipping will be available.

I've used various hooks as to where this is displayed (product page, cart, checkout etc) but what I am having real trouble with is how to round the cost off.

It is set to offer free shipping if customer spends at least 59 dollars. But if the customer add products for `58.xx` the message will show as, `"Spend 0.1223242 dollars more and get free shipping"`.

How do I change that into TWO decimals and how do I make it understand that `0.1223` equals `0.10` and that `0.15544` equals `0.2` and so forth? (I hope this is clear and easy enough to understand).

Here is the code I use:

```
function show_shipping_message() {
    global $woocommerce;  
    $total_cart = $woocommerce->cart->total;
    $limit_free_shipping = 59;

    if ($total_cart != 0 && $total_cart < $limit_free_shipping) { 
    $dif = $limit_free_shipping - $total_cart;

    ?>
    <p class="free-shipping-notice" >
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/shipping-icon.png"> <?php _e('TEXT', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN); ?> <?php echo $dif; ?> <?php _e('dollar, TEXT', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN); ?> <strong><?php _e('TEXT', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN); ?></strong>
    </p>

    <?php
    } 
    }
```

If someone can help then I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance. If any one knows how to make it auto-update after removing an item from the mini-cart that would be very good. Again, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use this function `wc_price( $price );` to format your price properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the functions `round()` with `number_format()` this way:

```
echo number_format( round(0.1223242, 1), 2 ); // will display: 0.10
```

You will get a price that will be first rounded to one decimal, but displayed in 2 decimals as you wanted.

---

You can also use `round()` with Woocommerce `wc_price()` formatting price function:

```
echo wc_price( round(0.1223242, 1) ); // will display: $0.10
```

You will get a formatted price *(rounded in to one decimal)* but displayed as other Woocommerce prices *(2 decimals display with the currency symbol)*...

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but that does not work. I tried with a product that costs 58 and the message does not show. I might be doing it wrong, but I copied your code from above.

Comment: @LearningHowtoCode Sorry it works… Just try this line: `echo number_format( round(0.1223242, 1), 2 ); // will display: 0.10` … It just works

Comment: I must be understanding you wrong, can you please explain where I put that echo? Nothing shows up using this code with a product that costs 58.69:

        '<p class="free-shipping-notice" >
        <img src="<?php echo $image_link ?>"> <?php _e('TEXT'); ?> <?php echo number_format( round(0.1223242, 1), 2 ); ?> <strong><?php _e('TEXT'); ?></strong>
        </p>'

Comment: @LearningHowtoCode This is just for testing an output of a float number with multiple decimals that will be rounded to 1 decimal and displayed with 2 decimals. Now in stackOverFlow you can't ask multiple questions in one. So for I question => 1 answer.